# SQL - Multi Table Joining with 1-1 and 1 - Many relationship

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to learn SQL and want to understand a scenario where i can Join 2 separate queries.

1. I have my APP_MTRX table would join with  Cust Table to retrieve all the records whose TYPE_ORD_NUM = 0 or 1
2. I need to join ADD_DTLS Table with SHR_ADR table based on SHR_ADR_ID and need to retrieve all the columns whose adr_type_id is either 0 or 1 again
3. joining the result of 1 and 2

below is my SQL

```
select * from app_mtrx ABC
left join cust on cust.cust_id = ABC.cust_id and abc.cust_ty_ord = 0
left join cust BBC on cust.cust_id = BBC.cust_id and abc.cust_ty_ord = 1 
left join add_dtls DEF ON DEF.cust_id=BBC.cust_id
left join shr_adr SHR on shr.shr_adr_id = def.shr_Adr_id
```

Can you please suggest if this is the correct approach and also if it is joining my 1 & 2 correctly....

Comment: why left join? inner join will work also. Rest approach looks nice. Instead of select *, use table_name.column_name to get columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  * FROM APP_MTRX am INNER JOIN Cust c
ON  am.cust_id  = c.cust_id 
AND  am.cust_ty_ord in (0,1)
INNER JOIN add_dtls  ad
ON ad.cust_id=c.cust_id
INNER JOIN shr_adr sh
ON ad.shr_adr_id = sh.shr_Adr_id
AND ad.adr_type_id in (0,1)
```